# Manually opening a Java 7 auto-managed resource

Tags: java, java-7, resource-management

So Java 7 has a nifty feature that automatically closes an `AutoCloseable` class. If I have `Bar` implement `Closeable` (which in turn extends `AutoCloseable`), and have a way to get an open `Bar` from a `Foo`, I can do this:

```
try(Bar bar=foo.openBar())
  //do something
}
```

...and `bar` will automatically be closed, just as if it were put in a `finally` clause. Lovely.

But what if I want to get a `Bar` and open it later? Because maybe a `Bar` is like a `File` and merely identifies a resource; I may want to identify a lot of them, but only open them when necessary.

```
Bar bar=foo.getBar();
try(bar.open())  //doesn't work
  //do something
}
```

But the Java 7 auto-managed approach requires me to assign a variable in the `try` clause, no?

So maybe I can be clever and have `Bar.open()` return `this` (i.e. the `Bar` instance), so that I can do this:

```
try(Bar bar=foo.getBar().open())
  //do something
}
```

This functions as I want, but it gives me a warning that the intermediate `Bar` instance is never closed.

So maybe I can do this:

```
Bar bar=foo.getBar();
try(Bar temp=bar.open())
  //do something
}
```

This too functions the way I want, but besides being ugly as heck, I still get a warning---this time that the first `bar` variable is never closed.

So maybe I can put the `bar.open()` call inside the protected block, like this:

```
try(Bar bar=foo.getBar())
  bar.open();
  //do something
}
```

That will work the way I want---most of the time. But what if `bar.open()` throws an exception? Java 7 will try to close `bar`, which, in my implementation, will throw an `IllegalStateException` because you can't close something that has never been opened. And so it should, right? Because if someone tries to close a `Bar` instance before it has been opened, something is screwy, and we want a fail-fast approach instead of letting the problem propagate and surface at an unknown time.

But maybe I *really* want to use auto-resource management, and so I consider relaxing `Bar.close()` so that you can close it at any time, even if you haven't opened the `Bar`. But now look what I'm doing: I'm changing my API (arguably making it inferior) just to use some syntactic compiler sugar!!

Any other ideas? I want to use Java 7 auto-resource management so that Java 7 will close my resource automatically, but *I* want to decide when to open it, which may not necessarily be at the moment I *acquire* the resource.

Answer (score 1):

**One idea**

What about letting it be closed twice and do this:

```
try (Bar bar=foo.getBar()) {
  try(bar=bar.open()) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

That's still pretty ugly and you do have to write some code to make the sugar work.

**Another idea**

Or just have two classes. One that holds the state information until you want to open it. Then there is another one that you create from the first and it really does open. (Sort of like a `File` and an `FileInputStream`.)

```
BarInfo barInfo = foo.getBarInfo();
...
try (Bar bar = barInfo.open()) {
   // do stuff with it
}
```

Comment: The first pretty much negates the syntactic sugar---maybe we could call it _syntactic bitter_! :) But the second option is interesting; I'll think more on it...

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I have it! I'll have two distinct methods in the API! One will be `Foo.getBar()` which simply returns a `Bar` instance. The second will be `Foo.openBar()`, which is just a convenience method that first calls `Foo.getBar()` and then calls `Bar.open()` like this:

```
public Bar openBar() {
  Bar bar=getBar();
  bar.open();
  return bar;
}
```

This way, one can use auto-resource-management by calling `Foo.openBar()`:

```
try(Bar bar=foo.openBar()) {
  //do something
}
```

When one wants to simply get a `Bar` instance to be used later, one can call `Foo.getBar()`. Unfortunately this still doesn't allow you to do auto-resource-management if you wait until later to open it, but maybe this approach will satisfy a common use case while still allowing flexibility.